# What does no input on raw_input("") give?

Tags: python, debugging, raw-input

I'm very new to python so apologize if this question sounds dumb, but:
I can't seem to figure out what `raw_input("")` returns if I just hit Enter.
I have a couple lines of code below

```
var = raw_input("")
if x == "":
    var = False
else:
    print("didn't work!")
```

The program doesn't seem to treat my if statement as true, it always prints my "didn't work!" line.
I also tried `if x == '':` and `if x == None:` but neither of these seem to work.

Printing the `var` variable obviously shows me nothing useful and I'm struggling with the debugger.

Comment: You assign the result of `raw_input` to `var`, not to `x`, so that's probably it.

Comment: That's because `x` doesn't exist or at least doesn't come from input

Comment: The million dollar question is:  What's the value of `x`?

Comment: BTW, to figure out what it returns you may just print its `repr`: `var = raw_input()` `print repr(var)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var = raw_input("")
if x == "":
```

Here you are saving your input in `var` and checking `x == ""` which will not work

You need to change it to `if var == "":`

Comment: Welp. Thank you! I was so focused on what I thought was wrong that I overlooked the simplest error.